# How to use jpeglib

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, libjpeg

I'm trying to use jpeglib to write a jpeg file to my own, without use the pre-build functions like jpeg_compress etc etc, but writing headers and tables individually... And here there are a lots of problem...

I'm using Windows and Visual Studio, so I tried to install the .exe file from gnuwin site and include in my code the 4 header files of the "include" folder, but when I try to call some functions like write_file_header, jpeg_stdio_dest etc etc, it says that there is a missing link, so I must include every .c file where those function are implemented...

I tried to include the src files too, but same result... every example I find includes only the header jpeglib.h and nothing else, but in this way I cannot use the functions I need, so my question is, how can I use those libraries properly?
thank you

Edit: the error message is error C3861: identifier not found... simply, when i try to call some function situated in some .c file of the libjpeg, the compiler cannot found where those function are...

Edit n.2:here the start of function:

```
#include "jpeglib.h"
#include "jerror.h"
#include "Common.h"

void jpeg(unsigned int *Src, int srclen, unsigned int *cod, unsigned int *length){

struct jpeg_compress_struct cinfo;

write_file_header(&cinfo); <- here is the problem... how can i access that function?
```

Answer (score 0):

You should **not** include the `.c` files directly, you have to tell your compiler to *link* against the library like in [this tutorial](http://www.steptools.com/support/stdev_docs/help/settings_vc10.html).

The jpeg library has to be built separately.

Comment: i did it, but it be useless, no chancge to the output messages... if it was so simple, i wouldn't post here :)

Comment: Maybe you should update your question with the exact error messages your compiler/linker produces.

Comment: jpeg library might be built separately, but this is not necessary. One can include the files into project as well and this is in fact a simpler thing to do.

Comment: well, but it doesn't work, nor if i built it semparately and nor if i use src file as they are, this is the problem

Comment: C3861 means that a symbol is not found during compilation. Does the compiler find the correct header files of the library? Do you make the correct `#include "..."` statements? You obviously need to give us some more information.

Comment: of course i include the proper header, but the issues is that function that i want to call isn't in that file, but in another .c file... it was logically to think that if i had included the jpeglib.h header I would have had access to all of the function, but is not so...

Comment: Okay, to clarify this: If the function is in no public header, the designer of the library simply does not *want* you to use that function (for whatever reason).

Comment: well, if it is real and i'm not suppose to call directly function like write_file_header, how can i write a jpeg header? someone suggest me to use libjpeg and function write_file_header to start explore the possibilities, but now?

Comment: After looking up the `write_file_header` function, I believe it really is not for a direct use. Maybe you have to look for another way to achieve what you want to do.

Comment: i was afraid of this... this is a very very bad conclusion, so do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Haha yeah, everyone knows chinese here i guess.

Comment: Hm, one and a half year ago, the link actually pointed to a page containing *english* documentation. All the documentation stuff can also be found in the official CVS here: http://libjpeg.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/libjpeg/libjpeg/